# IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id for fragment

Tags: android

I am getting

```
11-13 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.makemyday/com.example.makemyday.ActionDetailActivity}:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f050007 (com.example.makemyday:id/action_detail_container) for fragment ActionDetailFragment{41e9add8 #0 id=0x7f050007}
```

Code for action_detail_activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_detail);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            String id= getIntent().getStringExtra(ActionDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
            arguments.putString(ActionDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            ActionDetailFragment fragment = new ActionDetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.action_detail_container, fragment);

            SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
            ImageFragment imageFragment;
            Toast.makeText(this, ActionDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(id.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "here1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                //map=mapFragment.getMap();
            }
            else if(id.equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "here2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //imageFragment = (ImageFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.picture_upload);
                imageFragment=new ImageFragment();
                ft.add(R.id.imageContainer, imageFragment);

            }

            ft.commit();              
        }
    }
```

Code for activity_action_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+android:id/outer_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
tools:context=".ItemDetailActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/action_detail_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/imageContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/start_time_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="from" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please can someone answer this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

No need to use `@+android:id` for framelayout only
 fragement listview need `@+android:id`

for linearlayout also use

```
android:id="@+id/outer_container"
```

and

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/action_detail_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
```

**EDIT:**

`@+android:id` means you are referring to an `FrameLayout` defined in the android namespace. `@+id` defining your own `Id` to a view.

Comment: @Ankita `@+android:id` means you are referring to an FrameLayout defined in the android namespace. `@+id` defining your own Id to a view.

Answer (score 0):

Very Good..This saved me too..
android:id="@+id/container"

was missing in my code.